# Why isn't Getopt::Long initializing any values?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to write a quick script that I can pass different switches to for interacting with a web API that returns text based on what URL I query. So instead of trying to copy/paste the URL and whatever, I can just run script.pl --history for example... Anyways, my code looks something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use WWW::Curl::Easy;

my $APIKEY = "myapikey";

my $ip;
my $hist;
my $health;
my $url;
#... etc

GetOptions(
    'ip=s' => \$ip,
    'history' => \$history
    'health' => \$health
) or die "Useage: blah blah" if $history and not $ip;

if ($health) {
    $url = "appropriateurlhere";
}

#curl logic/handling/printing/etc
```

So if I tried to do script.pl --health, and do a print "$health" it should have been set to some kind of true value, but it's not. It's undefined... I can't figure out why.

Comment: Too much to redact, it was more expedient to do it that way, my apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the if statement modifier:

```
GetOptions(
    'ip=s'    => \$ip,
    'history' => \$history
    'health'  => \$health
) or die "Useage: blah blah" if $history and not $ip;  # <-- remove this if;
```

GetOptions is never being called because `$history` is undef when that if is reached.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine (besides the missing `,`), but there's an error here:

```
GetOptions(
    'ip=s' => \$ip,
    'history' => \$history
    'health' => \$health
) or die "Useage: blah blah" 
if $history and not $ip;
```

Since `$history` is undefined, the whole `GetOptions` isn't executed due to that `if`. Also you shouldn't use `if X and not Y`, but rather `if X && ! Y`.